# How to filter rows (corrections in transactions) - R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a transactional dataset (Online Retail in UCI Machine Learning repository). In the dataset, we have some transactions (1 transaction = 1 row) and its correction (the same row with a different InvoiceCode and negative quantity).

Example:

[Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc3HF.jpg)

I tried:

```
Transactions <- data3[duplicated(data3[,c(data3$StockCode, data3$Description, data3$UnitPrice data3$CustomerID, data3$Country)])]
```

But the code didn't work as I expected. Could anyone suggest how I could do it? Thank you.

Link to the original dataset: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+retail

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to filter out all corrections, then you should remove all the records with the value of `Quantity < 0`:

```
df <- data.frame(InvoiceNo=c("C551685","551697"),
                 StockCode=c("POST","POST"),
                 Description=c("POSTAGE","POSTAGE"),
                 Quantity=c(-1,1),
                 InvoiceDate=c("5/3/2011 12:51","5/3/2011 13:46"),
                 UnitPrice=c(8142.75,8142.75),
                 CustomerID=c(16029,16029),
                 Country=c("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

df
#  InvoiceNo StockCode Description Quantity    InvoiceDate UnitPrice CustomerID        Country
#1   C551685      POST     POSTAGE       -1 5/3/2011 12:51   8142.75      16029 United Kingdom
#2    551697      POST     POSTAGE        1 5/3/2011 13:46   8142.75      16029 United Kingdom

#Filter out all corrections:
df[df$Quantity < 0, ]
#  InvoiceNo StockCode Description Quantity    InvoiceDate UnitPrice CustomerID        Country
#1   C551685      POST     POSTAGE       -1 5/3/2011 12:51   8142.75      16029 United Kingdom
```

If you want to remove all the transactions then:

```
#Filter out all transactions:
df[df$Quantity > 0, ]
#  InvoiceNo StockCode Description Quantity    InvoiceDate UnitPrice CustomerID        Country
#2    551697      POST     POSTAGE        1 5/3/2011 13:46   8142.75      16029 United Kingdom
```